# Ubuntu 18.04 system user prompting for password

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I added a user to run a specific service using the command:

```
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false userName
```

I then try to run the service manually (after changing ownership of the service) by using:

```
su userName -c "./path/to/service"
```

Then I get a password prompt for which I do not know the password. I thought that system users weren't supposed to have passwords. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check https://askubuntu.com/questions/695701/what-is-the-default-password-when-you-create-new-user-in-ubuntu In short - you need to use root user to set password with command `passwd`.

Comment: Thanks Shan, I used that and got it to work, but I'm still looking for an option that doesn't require a password. I'm not positive but I think that may be a reason my service isn't working. From all the documentation I've read, system users should not require a password correct? I tried running `sudo passwd -d userName` and it's still prompting me for a password.